# Is there a way to make certain for loop iterations different?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

**JavaScript**. Is there a way to get a `for loop` do things slightly differently on every second (fifth etc.) iteration from what it is doing "by default"?

```
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  a += 5;
  b += a;
}
```

What if I want to add to `a` not `5` but `10` *on every second iteration* and add to `b` not `a` but `b` itself *on every fifth iteration* of the loop? Is this doable? Thank you!

Comment: Add some if statements to do things conditionally.

Comment: Your problem is a bit vague but I let you have a look at the `switch` statement. Unless you can do it with a data driven approach (putting your cases in a data structure then apply it "blindly").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulus operator % to find out whether `i` is evenly divisible by the "every Nth" value.

This will run both clauses on the first (zeroth) iteration, since zero is so divisible; you might want `i % 2 == 1` and `i % 5 == 4` instead, depending.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0) {
    a += 5;
  }
  if(i % 5 == 0) {
    b += a;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if this solves the zero-iteration problem?

`if (i > 0 && i % 26 === 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  if(i%2 === 0) {
     a += 10;
  } else {
     a += 5;
  }
  if(i%5 === 0) {
     b+= =b;
  } else {
     b += a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this:

```
for (var i = 0; I <n.length; i++){
  if( i + 1 / 2) {
    a += 10;
    b += a
  }else if ( i + 1 / 5) {
    a += 5;
    b += b
  } else {
   a += 5;
   b += a;
  }
}
```